# How to nuke a Cocoapods installation and start over with Github master

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, cocoapods

I am presently taking a course in iOS development and we use Github to submit work to instructors. Last night, I did an assignment on a project I've been working on for several days, committed the repo and stopped for the day.

This morning, I began another lesson that involved installing Cocoapods. I created a branch off of last night's branch (not the master) and installed a Cocoapod on it (Xcode was closed while I installed a Cocoapod). When I realized I was working off the wrong branch, I switched to the master branch and typed

`git branch -d install-cocoapods` to remove the local branch

I then checked out the master, opened it in Xcode thinking I'd see my master file, but I see remnants of Cocoapods. I checked Github and I see the last update was last night, but I can't get rid of the local references to the Cocoapods I attempted to install in on the wrong branch from this morning.

I checked Github and the project I saved last night is there, but I've been unsuccessful nuking local references to my project. How would I get rid of them and start with a clean "master" file from Github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all Pod files with this command:

```
rm -rf Podfile.lock Pods/
```

Stash all changes and then move to master:

```
git stash -a
git checkout master
```

Now write new `Podfile` and run:

```
pod install
```

Comment: Thank you! I've seen snippets of answers, but nothing that completely got rid of the remnants of the old file. I was hesitant to move forward with anything, as it felt like I was about to turn a muck up into a muck up of a muck up. Thank you again for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `git clean -fxd`.

This single command will remove all untracked and ignored files and directories, and, most of the time, take your repo back to it's "cleanest" state.

But beware that this command will potentially remove any files that haven't been tracked. So please make sure that you have all the files you want to keep tracked.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Thank you for reading the question.